# ubuntu - using imagemagick convert utlity to convert image into a multipage pdf

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick-convert

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and am trying to use the `convert` utility to convert a PNG image into a PDF file.  How can I specify that the PDF image should be multiple pages. I see examples of a single pdf into multiple images but not the other way around

```
convert -quality 100 -density 800x600 aaaaaaaaa.png multipage%d.pdf
```

I tried the below based on this blog [ubuntu-linux-command-line-tool-to-convert-pdf-to-image-and-from-image-to-pdf](http://harikrish.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ubuntu-linux-command-line-tool-to-convert-pdf-to-image-and-from-image-to-pdf/)

But it did not work.

Comment: Do you mean several png-files into one pdf? If so `convert *.png file.pdf` will do the trick. Or split one image over multiple pages?

Comment: One image into multiple pages

Comment: don't know if it can be done. One approach is to crop the image yourself into suitable pieces and then put those into the pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can crop each image into sections and then put it back together like this. the dimensions are the size it will crop each part of the page into.

```
convert aaaaaaaaa.png -crop 943x1360 +repage multipage.pdf
```